# Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Terminal Server and Ubuntu 11.10 - how do I backup from my own pc on remote desktop?

Tags: 11.10, windows, backup

We have Ubuntu 11.10 PCs as workstation at our office. I access my accounting program, Pastel, using RDP. The server where it's running on is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Terminal Server.

At present when I need to do my backups for Pastel, I have to physically insert the USB into the server in our data centre. This is not ideal because of access restrictions.

My question – how do I backup from my own pc on remote desktop? Surely it should be possible to insert into the local USB but backup a file on the remote server? Is there some other way of accessing the drive locally?

Answer (score 1):

You may try remmina rdp client.
I think it allows to use shared folders between the server and client.